# "unsupported_grant_type" error in angular user Authentication with $resource

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0

**My Issue**

Everything working fine with $post but when I update it to $resource,

I am getting error of **unsupported_grant_type**.

I tried many solutions from SO, but unable to resolve this issue.

Below is my code.

**Controller**

```
 $scope.login = function () {
        authService.login($scope.loginData).promise.then(function (response) {
            if (document.referrer != "" && document.referrer != window.location.href) {
                window.location.href = document.referrer;
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "/Roles/Index"
            }
        }
    };
```

**Service**

```
app.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', '$resource', '$rootScope',
    function ($http, $q, localStorageService, $resource, $rootScope) {

    var authServiceFactory = {};

    var _authentication = {
        isAuth: false,
        userName: ""
    };

    var url = function (relativeUrl) {
        return $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + '/api/' + relativeUrl;
    };

    var authResource = $resource(url('account/:id'), null, {
        register: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url('account/register')
        },
        login: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + '/token'                
        }           
    },
    {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });

    var _login = function (loginData) {
       // var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;

        loginData.grant_type = "password";
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        authResource.login($.param(loginData)).$promise
            .then(function (response) {
                localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName });

                _authentication.isAuth = true;
                _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;

                deferred.resolve(response);
            });
        return deferred;
    };       

    var _fillAuthData = function () {

        var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
        if (authData) {
            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = authData.userName;
        }
    }

    authServiceFactory.saveRegistration = _saveRegistration;
    authServiceFactory.login = _login;
    authServiceFactory.logOut = _logOut;
    authServiceFactory.fillAuthData = _fillAuthData;
    authServiceFactory.authentication = _authentication;

    return authServiceFactory;
}]);
```

**What I found from so many tries?**

I found that, My request does not have any headers.

Comment: default data transform is json for `$http`

Comment: @charlietfl, actually I am new  in angular, can you please give me some more guidence?

Comment: Have you tried to compare HTTP authentication requests from your working version to the problematic `$resource` variation?

Comment: Yes, there are several differences like call method from Post to Optional and Access-Headers etc..